# ECS: CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Get "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-fargate

I am new at Terraform IaC and AWS and am simply trying to push a docker image of JMeter to an ECR repository and have a Fargate instance in ECS use it. Due to security policies, this Fargate instance must be in a private subnet. Therefore, internet access needs to occur through a NAT Gateway. I have been bashing my head against a wall trying to get ECS to pull the image from my ECR. I have a deploy script that pushes it to the right place, and I have checked the ECR, IAM Permissions for the execution role, and my network configuration about a hundred times. Yet, upon task execution the tasks start, stop, and I continue to get errors such as

```
CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Get "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Here is the terraform code I am trying to provision:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
}
# VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "jmeter_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_support = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
}

resource "aws_subnet" "jmeter_public_subnet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.jmeter_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${var.aws_region}a"
  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc.jmeter_vpc
  ]
}

resource "aws_subnet" "jmeter_private_subnet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.jmeter_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${var.aws_region}a"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc.jmeter_vpc
  ]
}

resource "aws_eip" "nat_gateway_eip" {
  vpc = true
  tags = {
    name = "jmeter-eip"
  }
}

# Internet Gateway for the public subnet
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "jmeter_ig" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.jmeter_vpc.id
  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc.jmeter_vpc
  ]
}

# NAT Gateway for access to API from JMeter Instance
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "jmeter_nat_gateway" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat_gateway_eip.id
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.jmeter_public_subnet.id
  depends_on = [
    aws_internet_gateway.jmeter_ig,
    aws_eip.nat_gateway_eip

  ]
}

# Route Tables
resource "aws_route_table" "jmeter_public_rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.jmeter_vpc.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.jmeter_ig.id
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc.jmeter_vpc
  ]

}

resource "aws_route_table" "jmeter_private_rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.jmeter_vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.jmeter_nat_gateway.id
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_nat_gateway.jmeter_nat_gateway
  ]
}


#Route Table Associations
resource "aws_route_table_association" "jmeter_public_rt_association" {
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.jmeter_public_subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.jmeter_public_rt.id
  depends_on = [
    aws_route_table.jmeter_public_rt,
    aws_subnet.jmeter_public_subnet
  ]
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "jmeter_private_rt_association" {
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.jmeter_private_subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.jmeter_private_rt.id
  depends_on = [
    aws_route_table.jmeter_private_rt,
    aws_subnet.jmeter_private_subnet
  ]
}


#Keep this traffic unrestricted for now, cull later
resource "aws_security_group" "jmeter_security_group" {
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.jmeter_vpc.id

  ingress {
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol = "-1"
  }
  #ingress {
  #  from_port   = 80
  #  to_port     = 80
  #  protocol    = "tcp"
  #  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  #}

  #ingress {
  #  from_port   = 443
  #  to_port     = 443
  #  protocol    = "tcp"
  #  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  #}
  egress {
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc.jmeter_vpc
  ]
}

# ECS Cluster for image
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "jmeter_cluster" {
  name = "jmeter-cluster"

  setting {
    name = "containerInsights"
    value = "enabled"
  }

  configuration {
    execute_command_configuration {
      logging = "OVERRIDE"
      log_configuration {
        cloud_watch_log_group_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.jmeter_log_group.name
        s3_bucket_name             = aws_s3_bucket.jmeter_s3.bucket
      }
    }
  }
}


# Create ECR Repository for JMeter Image
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "jmeter_ecr" {
  name = var.ecr_repository_name
  force_delete = true
}

data "aws_ecr_repository" "jmeter_ecr_data" {
  name = aws_ecr_repository.jmeter_ecr.name
  depends_on = [
    aws_ecr_repository.jmeter_ecr
  ]
}


# Task definition for JMeter instance, network configuration provided by script
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "jmeter_task_def" {
  family = "jmeter-task"
  cpu = 1024
  memory = 4096
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name = "jmeter_task"
      image = "${aws_ecr_repository.jmeter_ecr.repository_url}:latest"
      log_configuration = {
        log_driver = "awslogs",
        options = {
          "awslogs-group" = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.jmeter_log_group.name
          "awslogs-region" = var.aws_region
        }
      }
    },
  ])
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode = "awsvpc"

  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.fargate_execution.arn
  task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.fargate_task.arn
  depends_on = [
    aws_cloudwatch_log_group.jmeter_log_group,
    aws_iam_role.fargate_execution,
    data.aws_ecr_repository.jmeter_ecr_data
  ]
}

# ECS Service for this instance
resource "aws_ecs_service" "jmeter_service" {
  name            = "jmeter-service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.jmeter_cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.jmeter_task_def.arn
  launch_type = "FARGATE"
  platform_version = "1.3.0"
  desired_count   = 1

  network_configuration {
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.jmeter_security_group.id]
    subnets         = [aws_subnet.jmeter_private_subnet.id]
  }

  deployment_controller {
    type = "ECS"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_ecs_cluster.jmeter_cluster,
    aws_ecs_task_definition.jmeter_task_def,
    aws_security_group.jmeter_security_group,
    aws_subnet.jmeter_private_subnet
  ]
}


data "aws_iam_policy_document" "fargate-role-policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs.amazonaws.com", "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
resource "aws_iam_policy" "fargate_execution" {
  name   = "fargate_execution_policy"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
            "ecr:BatchGetImage",
            "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
depends_on = [
  aws_ecr_repository.jmeter_ecr
]
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "fargate_task" {
  name   = "fargate_task_policy"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "fargate_execution" {
  name               = "fargate_execution_role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.fargate-role-policy.json
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "fargate_task" {
  name               = "fargate_task_role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.fargate-role-policy.json
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "fargate-execution" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.fargate_execution.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.fargate_execution.arn
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "fargate-task" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.fargate_task.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.fargate_task.arn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I run your program (with my ECR image), and everything works as expected. There are no connectivity issues what so ever. Thus whatever you are experiences can be due to:

1. External factors not presented in the question, e.g. manual changes to network settings, ecr, etc.
2. Using different code than in the question

Comment: I am trying to push and pull from a private ECR repository, and I believe the fargate execution role is set up properly for that. Could it be an issue with the container image itself that I'm trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a timeout is typically related to something networking or Security Group related.  Here are some random things I can think of to check:

- To smoke out if its a network/routing issue when trying to route out of via the NAT, you can try adding a ECR VPC endpoint associated with the subnet that you are running the Task in to see if there is a different result.
- Based on skimming your template, I see that all egress traffic is allowed on the Security Group can you confirm this is applied via the ECS console?
- Probably not a permission issue based on the error, but are you using KMS encryption for anything?
- Again, probably not a permission issue - but we have these two IAM Managed Policies associated with our ECS Execution Role that you may want to try associating.

  - `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy`
  - `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceEventsRole`